# ORMLite Asynchronous operations

Tags: java, android, database, orm, ormlite

I was reading documentation but I haven't found information If operations performed ORMlite's DAOs are asynchronous. Does anybody know if they are?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

There exists a class BaseOrmLiteLoader that extends an asynctaskloader class from android.

http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-android/com/j256/ormlite/android/apptools/BaseOrmLiteLoader.html